# proof by induction: If $n^2$ is odd then $n$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do you use proof by induction(specifically) to show that for every positive odd $n$ integer $n^2$ is always odd. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need induction for that. And your title does not agree with your question.

Comment: The difference between $n^2$ and $n$ is $n(n-1)$, the product of two consecutive integers, hence even

Comment: Your title and body do not agree. The title asks to prove that $n^2$ being odd implies that $n$ is odd, while the body asks for the other way around, I.E. that $n$ being odd implies that $n^2$ is odd. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $n^2$ is odd and $n$ is even. So $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n^2=n\cdot n=2k\cdot 2k=2\cdot(2k^2)\,\,$ is even, a contradiction.

The converse is trivial: If $n$ is odd then $n=2k+1$ and $n^2=(2k+1)^2=2(2k^2+2k)+1\,\,$ is odd.

Induction seems to be a bit of overkill here.

Comment: This proves that $n^2$ being odd implies that $n$ is odd, but doesn't necessarily show the implication goes both ways. These things are not always two way...  For example, $n$ being positive implies that $n^2$ is positive, but it is not true that $n^2$ being positive implies $n$ is positive

Comment: Reread the title of the question...that is what the question was about! The converse is trivial: If $n$ is odd then $n=2k+1$ and $n^2=(2k+1)^2=2(2k^2+2k)+1$ is odd.

Comment: you're right, I see the title and body of the post do not agree.... The OP is assuming the implications goes both ways without proving it. You chose to answer title, and I was looking at the body. I'll make a note to the OP about this. The proof in your comment above is probably my favorite part of your post though... I would include it in your answer!

Comment: I see. I am going to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n^2$ is odd, then $n^2=2m-1$ and $(n+1)^2=2(m+n)$.

Now $2$ is prime and $2\mid (n+1)^2$ so $2\mid n+1$ therefore $n+1=2r$ (for some integer $r$) whence $n=2r-1$ and $n$ is odd.

But the easier route is to show that the square of an even number is even, so an odd number can't be the square of an even number. So if an odd number is a square it must be the square of an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

$P(1)$ is true as $1$ is an odd number.

Let, $P(k)$ be true or If $k^2$ is odd then $k$ is odd.

We have to prove now that $P(k+1)$ is true.

$(k+1)^2= k^2 +2k +1=k(k+1)+(k+1)$.

Since $k(k+1)$ is product of two consecutive integers then it is even. $(k+1)^2= k(k+1)+(k+1)$ Here $(k+1)^2$ is odd and $k(k+1)$ is even so $(k+1)$ should be odd (as odd-even =odd).

We are done.

Comment: it isnt clear to me where you used $P(k)$ to show $P(k+1)$